# How is phase in a delay system represented by the equation of a straight line with slope equal to -n?

Tags: signal

## Background:

There is delay system concept given in this [link](http://imm.io/5xEH):

[image: Definition of delay system]

But, I did not understand the phase response of this dely system by diagram.
Diagram details are given in this [link](http://imm.io/5xEN) (crop shown below) as  figure 6.2:

[image]

## The problem restated:

I tried to understand phase of a delay system by this diagram but I failed to understand how the phase is represented by the equation of a straight line with slope equal to -n in figure 6.2.

Comment: Do you know how to convert the difference equation into a transfer function in the z domain? That would probably be the best first step to take into finding out why the phase response is what it is.

Comment: sorry no.. i did not study z doamin.. yet

Comment: To get up to speed, you may want to have a look at the first couple of parts of the following ebook section: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Transfer_Function_Analysis.html.  Once you know how to convert a difference equation into its z domain representation, the following section: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Frequency_Response_Analysis.html will tell you how to find the frequency and phase response.

Comment: "I failed to understand" is not a question.

Comment: You don't need the z-transform to understand phase.

Comment: @Bitrex, you may be a member of those here whom understand and love the z domain, but for most that do not know it, it is quite a hurdle. Significantly more complicated then frequency space when related to something "real" for a new learned. Do not misunderstand me, I am with you, Z domain is my only true love.

Comment: @Miss, why did you write Too Long; Didnt Read at the top of the question? If you didn't read the material on the topic, how can you expect to understand it?

Comment: @Martin - That was me, I edited it and the images took up a lot of space, obscuring the question way at the bottom.  So, I stuck a TLDR notice at the top.  It could be "Executive Summary" if you prefer.

Comment: @Brian: Do you realize that your english-teacher edits are causing all these old posts to float to the top, drowning out all the real stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is important to understand what phase is.

Consider a 1 Hz sine wave.  This means it goes through 360 degrees in one second. If you delay this wave by 1/2 second, that's 180 degrees phase shift.

Now consider a 2 Hz sine wave.  This means it goes through 720 degrees in one second. If you delay this wave by 1/2 second, that's 360 degrees phase shift.

By these examples, see how the phase at a constant time delay depends on frequency?

Comment: I am not sure I would have made as concise an example. Too many years with only using the z transform. I knew that was the reason, but turning the brain on is never easy.

Comment: @markages: i understand he applied formula for straight line.. taninver(b/a) .. so that mean phase changes depend on frequency..

Comment: @Miss You don't need a transcendental function to explain it... higher frequency means things are happening faster, so more change happens in a fixed amount of time.